# Nuxt.js static site and 404 page

Tags: nuxt.js, custom-error-pages, static-site

I have currently created a `pages/404.vue` file, then, in my server settings, I redirect any non existent url to /404.html (the generated page).

Apart me having to declare the file extension (it gives me redirect error if I redirect to /404), it seems to work fine, and I guess it will also give me an easy way to create other server error files, if needed.

However, following the documentation, I first tried adding `fallback: true` inside `generate:{ }`. This creates a `404.html` page in my root, but using a default Nuxt layout (an infinite loading wheel page).

I assumed that creating `layouts/error.vue` (as per docs) would do the trick, but didn't seem the case.

What is the right practice, and, if the documentation one is to follow, why my personalised error.vue wasn't working?
Thanks.

Comment: Any news on this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No answers received.

I removed the `pages/404.vue` in the end and created it as `layouts/error.vue`

error.vue was giving me erros related to default.vue, for some reasons, so I created a `layouts/basic.vue` layout as an (almost) empty container for error.vue.

The error page now works during dev and during the new nuxt start local testing on full static site (since nuxt 2.13), but still not on the live site, which I will check if related to server settings.

the above goes together with `generate: { fallback: true }` in nuxt.config.js (which creates the 404.html page)

Comment: do you have an update on this? I'm using AWS Amplify and it specifically ask for an actual 404 page/path. Should I go with having an actual 404.vue page?

Comment: no, if you are using `target: static`, then you want to add `generate { fallback: true }` in nuxt.config.js and the actual page in `layouts/error.vue` , then you need to redirect the errors in the server to the 404.html generated file

Answer (score 10):

In order to generate a 404 fallback page in nuxt.js you need to first set the generate option in your nuxt.config.js like this
`generate: { fallback: '404.html' }`

Then you need to create a new layout called error.vue in your layouts directory

```
layouts/error.vue
```

After you have done this you can `nuxt generate` followed by `nuxt start` to run your project with a fallback page for the 404 error.

Answer (score 6):

**NUXT 3 Update 2023:**

If you are using Nuxt 3, add `error.vue` to the **root directory**, NOT into `/pages` or `/layouts`

```
// /error.vue
<template>
    <div class="flex flex-col items-center">
            <div class="text-indigo-500 font-bold text-7xl">
                404
            </div>

            <div class="font-bold text-3xl xl:text-7xl lg:text-6xl md:text-5xl mt-10">
                This page does not exist
            </div>

            <div class="text-gray-400 font-medium text-sm md:text-xl lg:text-2xl mt-8">
                The page you are looking for could not be found.
            </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 3):

To create a 404 page, it is enough to create two new layouts with the names `error.vue` and `empty.vue` in the `layouts` folder.

If you want your 404 page to have a different structure from the project, use `layout:"empty"`, otherwise you can use the same `layout:"default"`.

see my codes...

```
// layouts/error.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <h1 v-if="error.statusCode === 404">Page not found</h1>
    <h1 v-else>An error occurred</h1>
    <NuxtLink to="/">Home page</NuxtLink>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'error',
  layout: 'empty', //OR layout:'default'
  props: {
    error: {
      type: Object,
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

And empty layout with custom structure can be as follows:

```
// layouts/empty.vue
<template>
   //your codes
   <Nuxt />
</template>
```